# How to replace specific strings to NSTextAttachment for show image

Tags: ios, swift

I will get a lot of message string

Like these:

`1.hello {{http://i.imgur.com/f1cqT3ut.jpg}} world {{http://i.imgur.com/f1cqT3ut.jpg}}`

`2.hi {{http://i.imgur.com/iVx9iqjt.jpg}} {{http://i.imgur.com/iVx9iqjt.jpg}} how {{http://i.imgur.com/ZpXgxiXt.jpg}} are {{http://i.imgur.com/rcdHObKt.jpg}} you {{http://i.imgur.com/yX5dHdet.jpg}} ? {{http://i.imgur.com/2iZSBKGt.jpg}}`

And I want to handle these messages

Like these:

1.[message handled 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXia9.png)

2.[message handled 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAymb.png)

Now I only know can use NSMutableAttributedString to show all handled messages and use NSTextAttachment to show the url images.

But I don't know how to replace and handle these messages.

Help me, please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume that each string will be setup like that, where the words and URL's are separated by spaces - and the URL's are all contained within two sets of curly brackets, you could create a method that would then take a string and split it into an array of substrings (separated by spaces), you could then check for a substring that starts with "{{" to know it's a URL. I just wrote something like this which would return an array of tuples where each tuple is an integer (correlating to the index of the URL within the array of substrings), and a string which represents the URL removed from the curly brackets.

```
func split(_ s: String) -> [(Int, String)] {

    // Separate the original string into an array of substrings separated by a space
    let separated = s.components(separatedBy: " ")
    // Filter the separated array to find the URLs that start with {{
    var urls = separated.filter{ $0.hasPrefix("{{") }
    // Map the urls array to get an array of ints correlating to their respective indices from the separated array
    let indicies = urls.map { separated.index(of: $0) }
    // create an empty array of Int and String tuples
    var tuples: [(Int, String)] = []

    // Loop through the url array 
    for i in 0 ..< urls .count {

        // Remove the left side (open) curly brackets
        urls[i] = urls[i].replacingOccurrences(of: "{{", with: "")
        // Remove the right side (close) curly brackets
        urls[i] = urls[i].replacingOccurrences(of: "}}", with: "")

        // Append the tuple with the url's index from the separated array and it's actual url value as a string
        tuples.append((indicies[i]!, urls [i]))
    }
    return tuples
}
```

You could then use this to split the words from the urls, and then fetch the images (that would be up to you - maybe use Alamofire or even just `NSURLSession`) and then since you have their original index from the array of substrings - you still know what order they go in. So re-arrange them based on original order once the asynchronous request comes back, and then use `UILabels` sandwiched in between `UIImageViews` (or vice-versa) to display the content in the way you're trying.

Comment: thanks a lot .
I saw the tuples has urls index and url, but how to use this tuples to constitute a complete NSMutableAttributedString？ I don't quite understand , sorry ><"

Comment: I found a bug, if the urls is same url, indicies will always found the first one...

Answer (score 0):

```
        let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string : "start of text")
    let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    image1Attachment.image = UIImage(named : "image name")
    let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)

    fullString.append(image1String)
    fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "End of text"))

    yourLabel.attributedText = fullString
```

This code is to shows a way that you want.Use for reference implement code as you need.